# Delayed incoming GTalk messages

Tags: google-talk

Recently, I performed a factory reset on my SGS (Froyo), since then all my incoming GTalk messages are seen arriving one hour before: if it is 5pm, the message is tagged 4PM.

Well, I could live with that, but the problem is that my responses are tagged with the right time, therefore any further incoming messages will be placed vertically before my messages.

I have tried changing the time, change time zones, accept network-provided time, and nothing seems to work...

Had this happened to you?How can I solve this problem?

Thanks

Comment: Sounds like an issue with Summer Time vs Daylight Savings Time? Most parts of the world are still running on Summer Time right now, which is generally +1 to your actual time zone.

Comment: That was it! I did something I haven't tried before: increase the time zone by +1 and manually decrease the phone time by one hour. Spot on! If you care to answer, I'll accept it. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This sounds like an issue with Summer Time vs Daylight Savings Time? Most parts of the world are still running on Summer Time right now, which is generally +1 hour to your actual time zone.

As well as checking your phone's time zone, check to see if you have the correct settings for summer time/daylight savings set.

Answer (score 1):

Try to delete the gtalk application data:

`Settings -> Application -> Application Settings`

choose the gtalk app and press delete data.

Comment: Thanks for answering, but it didn't work! :(